# how do I withdraw my submitted paper?

Tags: career

I submitted a paper and unfortunately, about a week later, found a glaring error in reasoning in one of the proofs. Since the paper had been submitted only 1 week, the journal website said it hadnt been sent out for review yet. So, I emailed the journal office IMMEDIATELY with a request to withdraw my paper. No response.

I sent another email to the journal office. No response.

Finally I emailed the chief editor with my request. No response :(

Its been a month. With some additional steps, I have been able to repair my proof and now I want to submit my paper to another journal. But I dont know if my paper has been successfully withdrawn or not. The journal website still says no referee has been picked.

What do I do? The journal in question is quite well known and the editors are powerful people. I am a junior mathematician; I dont want to piss anyone off. At the same time, I think I can have my paper accepted to another good journal by application season if I submit now. how much more should I wait?

Comment: I think this question is better asked at http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This seems quite unspecific to mathematics and thus off-topic for this site. The site Joel Reyes Noche mentioned seems like a good fit. Voted to close.   

Answer (score 13):

As an editor of 5 journals, I feel concerned by the case of this young person.

Multiple submission of the same paper is indeed misconduct - see e.g. the recent EMS code of practice:

http://www.euro-math-soc.eu/system/files/COP-approved.pdf

However, in your case, it seems that you took all necessary steps. If I were you, I'd keep in my files a copy of all unanswered messages, about withdrawal I'd send a final reminder to the chief editor (asking for acknowledgement of receipt), and I'd go ahead with submission to the new journal.

Comment: Don't forget to tick the "return receipt" box on your e-mail program when you send the reminder. It's always a good CYA practice.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Valette. I received a confirmation of withdrawal from the journal office 2 minutes back :) Seems like the second email to the Chief Editor did the trick. :)

Comment: but why don't you send the correct version to the same journal, if I may ask?

Comment: Just feels weird to send it to same journal. I just want to start over at a different journal with a clean slate...